# MUI: Moving pagination to the top of DataGrid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone have any idea on how I can move the standard `XGrid` pagination to above the table? Or am I going to have to create my own custom pagination and not use the inbuilt with `XGrid`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no public API to put the pagination component on the top, but you can use this CSS trick:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  grid: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column-reverse"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 100,
    maxColumns: 4
  });
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        className={classes.grid}
        autoHeight
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
        {...data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67112873/moving-pagination-to-top-header-of-table]

Comment: this is nearly perfect but I am also using the components prop to add the filtering etc, and it now appears at the bottom!

https://codesandbox.io/s/67112873moving-pagination-to-top-header-of-table-forked-2hf08?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @AlanGordon that's why it's called a trick and not a proper solution in all cases, it just reverses the list order so the filter normally on the top now is at the bottom. I have 1 more trick for you: You can set the filter to use absolute position and put it on top like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/67112873moving-pagination-to-top-header-of-table-forked-yo634?file=/demo.tsx:345-364).

Comment: This is so smart!

Comment: suppose we need pagination on top and bottom then how we can do that?

Comment: This will cause accessibility issues because the tab order is not as expected

Answer (score 2):

What I did in my project is I removed the pagination of the DataGrid by adding `hideFooterPagination` prop and added a TablePagination component on top of the table.